# Extjs Rollback model changes on store save failure

Tags: extjs, rollback

I am using ext-js 4.0.7, and I am trying to find the way to rollback changes in model if saving failed.

My store is

```
Ext.define('TEST.store.TestStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'testStore',
    model: 'TEST.model.TestModel',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'some/api',
        reader: 'json'
    }
});

...
var me=this,
testStore = me.getStore('TEST.store.TestStore');
me.test = testStore.getAt(0);

//here are I am changing it

me.test.save({
failure: function(record,operation) {
    console.log(test);
    test.reject();
    console.log(test);
}
});
```

But reject is not working. Is there any other way to clear this model?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS5 the method is store.rejectChanges();

If it is reject() in v4, then perhaps you probably need to call it on the store rather than the record e.g. testStore.reject(); in your code above